# ElasticSearch aggregate by specific field in nested document, but do not filter it out

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a document(product) structure like :

```
{
                    "id": 112,
                    ....
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "in_stock": true,
                            "op_values": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Color",
                                    "value": "Red"
                                }
                            ],
                           ....
                        },
                        {
                            "in_stock": false,
                            "op_values": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Color",
                                    "value": "Blue"
                                }
                            ],
                           ....
                       }
}
```

I'm trying to aggregate all "op_values" in stock, but when I add in_stock term, it filters top-level document, and I do not have results in the bucket.

It is just a part of a big query to make it easier to read:

```
  .....  .....
 "aggs": {
                                    "filter": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "should": [
                                                {
                                                    "term": {
                                                        "options.in_stock": {
                                                            "value": true,
                                                            "boost": 1
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "term": {
                                                        "options.op_values.name": {
                                                            "value": "Color",
                                                            "boost": 1
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                               
    }
....
```

Just assume I have only 1 document, with different stock field value, when I aggregate I need to see only stock : true values, but I see both or none, depend on in_stock filter

Might inner hits be the solution? I could not make aggregation work with inner hits,   Am I trying to do something impossible for ES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Nested objects. This will make your options a list of separate documents in elasticsearch and allow to do such kind of operations.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

https://linuxhint.com/elasticsearch-nested-query/

**UPDATED**:
Lets say you have data like this

```
"options": [
        {
            "in_stock": "true",
            "op_values": [
                {
                    "name": "Color",
                    "value": "Pink"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "in_stock": "true",
            "op_values": [
                {
                    "name": "Color",
                    "value": "Red"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Color",
                    "value": "Black"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "in_stock": "false",
            "op_values": [
                {
                    "name": "Color",
                    "value": "Blue"
                }
            ]
        },
```

You want to get Result like this. So you have the Colors, but only that are in stock. Right?
[image]

To do that i use this aggregation.

```
{
"query": {
    "match_all": {}
},
"aggs": {
    "options": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "options"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "in_stock": {
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "options.in_stock": {
                                        "value": "true",
                                        "boost": 1
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "op_values": {
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "options.op_values"
                        },
                        "aggs": {
                            "colors": {
                                "terms": {
                                    "field": "options.op_values.value"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

It is a bit huge :)))), but hope fits your requirements.

Comment: it's already a nested document 
I have such a structure 
--top level 
----nested options (stock field here)
--------nested op_values (color field here)

please check the document structure in the post

Comment: So,  @bxN5 Then, if you already have it as nested - you have the wrong aggregation query to a nested objects. I added an example of aggregation that actually returns number of "in_stock" options.

Comment: Imagine we have only  1 document with a nested in-stock filter with different color options, as I posted in my question, I need to aggregate op_values taking into account in_stock
So as a result of aggregation, I need to see only "Red" option (Blue is out of stock), but when I add this filter per your suggestion, both options is disappearing, because we have only 1 top level product, and seems ES do not aggregate by this  if at least one option in a nested document is false

Comment: @bxN5, So, i think i finally understood what you want) I created 1 document, added a lot of options and op_values and returned only Colors that are in_stock.

Comment: Hope that helps, if not - lets continue. Now its personal)

Comment: I need to adopt it, but yes, seems it's working, дякую ! :)

Comment: so my mistake was I need to wrap in stock aggregation in op_values, and seems I did on the same level

Comment: nema za sho :-)